# Is League of Legends playable on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: installation, 13.10

Its been my main game since season 2 of it and i just switched to Linux and i wondered if its possible to play games League of Legends on Ubuntu 13.10? If possible can someone explain me how to or link me some tutorial for 13.10 ubuntu!

Thanks in advance

```
HP ProBook 4535s
```

Answer (score 2):

A step by step procedure has been published in the League of Legends forum at http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1946188&page=30

1. Go into Ubuntu software center and look up wine.
2. Install a program called winetricks and all the add-ons.
3. Once installed look up a program called PlayOnLinux and install it.
4. Open up PlayOnLinux then and Hit the Install a program on the right side of it.
5. Once that is open go up on the upper menu and hit games
6. Deselect commercial and select testing.
7. Scroll down and select League of legends

When you are on the last installation page deselect the box to auto run after finish

Once it is installed and everything is finished bring back up the PlayOnLinux program and run it.

Comment: Would be better if you could provide the gist of the solution here.

Comment: I can confirm this works. However, it seems to fail after a month or so for me, every time on every machine, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/585342/league-of-legends-will-not-launch-at-all-not-even-the-patcher-via-playonlinux